# OpenCascade: How to subdivide elongated triangles?

Tags: mesh, opencascade

I am using *OpenCascade* to import STEP/IGES as meshes in my software. Works nicely.

But I need small triangles, and the one I get are sometimes very large (in flat area), or very elongated (eg. when meshing a cylinder). The best would be to split triangle's edge bigger than some absolute value. Avoiding T vertices, too.

I was'nt able to google anything about that... So, currently, I pass the mesh to *OpenMesh*, apply the `OpenMesh::Subdivider::Uniform::LongestEdgeT` operator, then pass it back to my software. Tedious and costly when I manage several M triangles...

Questions:

1. Is there an equivalent in *OpenCascade* ?
2. Or a simple code snipet to implement my own loop to do so ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The meshing algorithm **BRepMesh_IncrementalMesh** coming with Open CASCADE Technology is mainly focused on two usage scenarios:

- **Visualization** in 3D Viewer. Large and prolonged triangles make no harm to presentation, as vertex normals ensure proper smooth shading. Deflection parameters allows managing presentation quality.
- Computing **Algorithms** using triangulation as approximation (to speed up calculations compared to the same algorithm working on exact geometry). In this case, deflection parameters determine the target precision of the algorithm. Large and prolonged triangles should not cause problems here, as deviation from exact geometry is controlled by meshing parameters.

There are, however, some categories of algorithms, where shape of mesh element is very important. **[Solvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solver)** (numerical simulation) make one of such categories, where unfortunate mesh elements may cause numerical instability or other issues. What exactly matters / cause issues depend on specific algorithm - this may include [element skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_mesh#Skewness), element aspect ratio, element size and elements grid. Some solvers work much better on quads rather than on triangles.

If you take a look onto meshing result of **BRepMesh_IncrementalMesh** algorithm, you may notice that not only large prolonged triangles, but entire mesh structure is somewhat suboptimal for solver algorithms:

[image: BRepMesh]

There are several options you may consider:

- **Triangulation refinement** algorithm. Such algorithm processes existing triangulation and tries *healing* some properties like skewness. This what does OpenMesh from your question, I suppose. Such postprocessing algorithm might give satisfactory results at good performance, but final result will dramatically depend on properties of original meshing algorithm. For the moment, OCCT doesn't have any refinement tool, although it is possible writing such algorithm on your own (I cannot give you a small code snippet, because such algorithm is not that small an trivial as it may look from a first glance).

  [image: Refined BRepMesh]
- Consider **alternative meshing algorithm**. Probably incomplete list:

  - **[Express Mesh](https://www.opencascade.com/content/express-mesh)** by Open Cascade (hence, working directly on OCCT shapes). This tool generates triangulation having nice grid-alike structure (for smooth surfaces), configurable element size and quad-dominant generation option. This is a commercial product though.
    [image: ExpressMesh]
  - **[Netgen](https://github.com/NGSolve/netgen)** mesher. This open source tool provides bindings to OCCT, and although it is focused on 3D tetrahedral mesh generation, it may be also used for generating a common triangular mesh. I cannot say something good about this tool - it was rather slow and unstable when I've seen its work many years ago.
  - **[MeshGems](http://www.meshgems.com/surface-meshing-meshgems-cadsurf.html)** surface meshing. Another commercial tool providing an interface to OCCT. Never worked with this product, so cannot share any opinion on it.
- Consider **improving BRepMesh_IncrementalMesh**. As OCCT is an open source framework, you may consider extending its meshing algorithm with more parameters and contribute to the project.

Comment: For completeness, the "instant meshes" open source project can also be used to effectively remesh surfaces https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes (and although not integrated with OCCT provides ready to go cross-platform binaries).